# which best event for touchscreen application?

Tags: vb.net, touch

I have developed an application using VB.NET that uses a touchscreen (it's a Point of Sales app). I have used button click events to execute the code like a normal Windows application. Is this correct way to do it, or should I use MouseUp and MouseDown events?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it **does not involve** a specific programming question. Also, have you tried it and what does it do?

Comment: thanks codexer, you are very helpful person!!!

Comment: codexer, i tied both of them, button click and button mouseup/down and both of them execute the process but i need to most perfect for TOUCHSCREEN friend!

Comment: If they are working, what is the issue? I'm assuming this is Windows Forms, so there is no touch related event.

Comment: yes,no touch events, but sometimes when click a button the application hang! (sometimes) so i'm wondering if button click event is the problem and may i have to change it to button mouseup event.

Comment: `i need to most perfect for TOUCHSCREEN` you are asking for recommendation's in which this is not the type of questions that ***are not answered*** here at SO. This type of problem is something you should evaluate as it's different among applications, specifics and etc...

Answer (score 3):

Using `Click` events is correct. On a touch screen, tapping a button will generate a `Click` event, just like it would if you clicked the button with a mouse.

*P.S. You mention in the comments that sometimes the application hangs when you click a button. This is most likely caused by the code that responds to the `Click` event, and is not related to using a touch screen.*

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into an issue on our Touch POS app yesterday.  The click event is fired twice in some cases on some monitors.  It seems that different touchscreen monitors handle the click even differently and some have software to prevent it others do not.  The specific issue was that our click event was being fired two times so clicking button "1" would result in "11"  Only happened when using the touchscreen not the mouse.   The first depress of the button would put "1" and then when you took your finger off the button another "1" would appear.  If you debugged the click event it would only be fired 1 time and just put 1 in the field.  If you took debug out it went back to 11.

Save yourself the headaches and use MOUSEUP.